# Unable to install docker on RHEL 8

Tags: docker

I am tying to installing docker on rhel 8.

I am getting the below error not sure why please help.

```
[root@mano mano]# yum install docker-ce-18.09.9
Cannot find a valid baseurl for repo: InstallMedia, ignoring this repo.
Last metadata expiration check: 0:11:14 ago on Fri 20 Sep 2019 02:42:53 PM IST.
Error: 
 Problem: package docker-ce-3:18.09.9-3.el7.x86_64 requires containerd.io >= 1.2.2-3, but none of the providers can be installed
  - cannot install the best candidate for the job
  - package containerd.io-1.2.2-3.3.el7.x86_64 is excluded
  - package containerd.io-1.2.2-3.el7.x86_64 is excluded
  - package containerd.io-1.2.4-3.1.el7.x86_64 is excluded
  - package containerd.io-1.2.5-3.1.el7.x86_64 is excluded
  - package containerd.io-1.2.6-3.2.el7.x86_64 is excluded
  - package containerd.io-1.2.6-3.3.el7.x86_64 is excluded
(try to add '--skip-broken' to skip uninstallable packages or '--nobest' to use not only best candidate packages)
```

I have installed containered.io

Comment: Did you follow the [docs](https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/docker-ce/centos/)?

Comment: @emix yes step by step didnt miss anything.

Answer (score 2):

RHEL have blocked [Containerd](https://containerd.io/) for some reason.

You have to manually install it by running the command line below;

```
yum -y install https://download.docker.com/linux/centos/7/x86_64/stable/Packages/containerd.io-1.2.6-3.3.el7.x86_64.rpm
```

After that, `yum install docker-ce` should works fine.

Note that you *must* also disable `firewalld`, otherwise DNS is broken.

For that, you can run:

```
systemctl disable firewalld
```

Comment: The OP meant RedHat 8; not 7. 

Comment: Nope, RHEL 8. RHEL7 doesn't use DNF. It appears to be caused by a bad commit to libsolv in RHEL8.

Comment: I get you. Thanks for the explanation. It will be great to update your answer with these details and reference. 

Answer (score -1):

For Rhel 8 try the following steps:

First, install DNF:

```
yum install DNF
```

```
dnf install -y dnf-utils \
  device-mapper-persistent-data \
  lvm2
dnf config-manager \ 
  --add-repo \
  https://download.docker.com/linux/centos/docker-ce.repo
dnf install docker-ce
systemctl start docker
systemctl enable docker
```

While installing, if you are prompted to accept the GPG key, accept the same by entering y

Comment: thank you for your response. I tried the above and its not working same error.